# Dependency management with conda-build -- how to get rid of redundancy and duplication?

Tags: python, conda

I have a conda-based project that contains an `environment.yml` file that lists project dependencies. I also want to use this project to build a conda package. For that, I created another file, `meta.yaml`, that also needs to list the dependencies.

Moreover, in  `meta.yaml`, one may specify separate dependencies for building, running and testing.

My questions are:

- What is the difference between the build and run dependencies in `meta.yaml`?
- Is there a way to synchronize between the packages (names and versions) listed in `environment.yml` and those listed in `meta.yaml`?

Answer (score 1):

Build dependencies are those required to build your project, while the run dependencies are those required to run the package once its installed. For instance, you may require a C compiler to build a C extension in your package, and then you'd require a (compatible) C library to run the package.  Or, if you have a pure Python package, your build dependencies are likely to be Python and setuptools, while your run dependencies will be any other package that you import from within your package. See [the documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#requirements-section) for further information, and note there is also a test requirements section where you can put dependencies that are only required to test your package.

As far as I know, there is no way to automatically "copy" packages between an `environment.yml` and a `meta.yml` file. You could conceivably script some way to do that (perhaps with a Makefile from which you run conda build), but that seems quite complex and at least as prone to failure as manually copying the dependencies back and forth. Moreover, the packages in the `environment.yml` file are likely to be only the run dependencies, or perhaps a mish-mash of build and run dependencies, in which case, you'd have to manually manage the dependencies in meta.yaml anyways.

Comment: If I read the documentation correctly if test requirements are not specified, then run dependencies are assumed https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/define-metadata.html#test-requirements

Comment: Not quite... dependencies specified in the test section are **additional** dependencies, in addition to the ones in the run section.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant.